# Geodesics on a Riemannian manifold under non-Levi-Civita connections

Tags: riemannian-geometry, geodesic, connections

I'm a beginner on this topic—so please comment if anything is ambiguous, unclear, or wrong. In particular, I'm trying to figure out how to think of geodesics under arbitrary connections.

## Background

Usually, when we talk about geodesics on a Riemannian manifold $(M, g)$, we mean geodesics *with respect to the Levi-Civita connection*.

We can also talk about a metric on connected $(M, g)$ induced by the metric $g$ given by $$
  d(a,b) = \inf\left\{\int_\gamma g(\gamma'(t), \gamma'(t))\, dt : \gamma(0) = a, \gamma(1) = b\right\}.
$$
In particular, if $(M,g)$ is geodesically complete, there exists a  geodesic curve with respect to the Levi-Civita connection from $a$ to $b$ of length $d(a, b)$.

---

## Question

What is the relationship between geodesics and the metric for an arbitrary connection $\nabla$?

In particular, does there exist a geodesic curve with respect to $\nabla$ from $a$ to $b$ of length $d(a,b)$?

What if $\nabla$ meets the first condition of a Levi-Civita connection, namely $\nabla g = 0$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2681614/what-does-a-nonsymmetric-connection-on-bbb-rn-look-like

Answer (score 2):

This question as stated is too broad to have a definite answer, I am afraid.

I would recommend the following article as a good introduction to the subject:

[1] **Vladimir S. Matveev,** Geodesically equivalent metrics in general relativity, [arxiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1101.2069v2).

To further advance in the subject, one could look at this article:

[2] **Michael Eastwood, Vladimir S. Matveev,** Metric connections in projective differential geometry, [arxiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/0806.3998).

On a different side, regarding the case of metric connection with torsion, perhaps the next article is of a certain interest:

[3] **Ilka Agricola, Christian Thier,** The geodesics of metric connections with vectorial torsion, [arxiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0309087v2).

Maybe, there are other directions, that I am not aware of.